# Vue.js: How to avoid error after updating store?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am building an app with vue.js and vuex that stores entries of household accounts (i.e. personal expenses and incomes). The entries are filtered by month; a slider can be used to change months. The current code is on [Github](https://github.com/juliangermek/haushaltsbuch).

Displaying existing entries works fine. The problem arises when I try to add a new entry. When I add an entry for an existing month, it works fine. But when I add an entry for a new month (i.e. a month for which no other entry exists yet), I get a myterious warning and a myterious error: `Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. This is likely a Vue internals bug.` `Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node`. Note: When I say month I mean month-year combination.

Any ideas where this error might be coming from?

Here is some more info about the current app. The current application looks like this:

[image]

My store looks like this:

```
const store = createStore({
  state() {
    return {
      categories: [
        {
          type: "expense",
          key: "living",
          value: "Wohnen",
        },
        ...
      ],

      entries: [
        {
          id: 1,
          date: "2020-10-15T14:48:00.000Z",
          type: "expense",
          category: "Lebensmittel",
          amount: 15.24,
          note: "Edeka",
        },
        ...
      ],
    };
  },

  getters: {
    sorted_entries(state) {
    // Returns all entries, sorted by date
      ...
      return sorted_entries;
    },

    categories(state) {
      return state.categories;
    },

    entriesMonths(state) {
      // Return an ordered arrays of all months present among entries
      // Ex.:{index: 0, month: "11", year: "2019", displayMonth: "November 2019"}
      ...
      return entriesMonths;
    },
  },

  mutations: {
    addEntry(state, entryData) {
      const newEntry = {
        id: new Date().toISOString(),
        date: entryData.date,
        type: entryData.type,
        category: entryData.category,
        amount: entryData.amount,
        note: entryData.note,
      };
      console.log("right before push")
      state.entries.push(newEntry);
    },
  },

  actions: {
    addEntry(context, entryData) {
      context.commit("addEntry", entryData); // Place to store in backend server
    },
  },
});
```

In `EntryList.vue` I get `sorted_entries` and `entriesMonths` from the store:

- `sorted_entries` is used to calculate `filtered_entries` which filters the entries according to what month is currently displayed by the slider (initialization: latest month among entries in store). `filtered_entries` is displayed as a list
- `entriesMonths` is passed to another component `MonthSelector.vue` which implements the slider to change months and emits the new month after a change to `EntryList.vue` so it can update `filtered_entries`.

New entries are added via `NewEntryForm.vue`. This component includes a form to ask the user for the new entry data. It then emits this data as an object to its parent `AddEntry.vue` which in turn sends it to the store. There an action triggers a mutation which adds the entry to the state.

Of cause there are a lot of more details to mention, but I don't know which are relevant to solving this problem. Please ask, if you need more info or have a look at the code ([Github](https://github.com/juliangermek/haushaltsbuch)).

Many thanks!

Comment: right after `console.log("right before push")` add a new line with `debugger;` and that will make the web browser stop in that line, inspect the current `state.entries` as well your object `newEntry`, remembering you can write an execute any code in the browser console while you're in debug mode - BTW, your action `addEntry` should actually be called `saveEntry` 

Comment: Good hint! I cannot find anything wrong with `newEntry` and also found out that it is added correctly to the store (by using `debugger` after `console.log("right before push")`. The problem remains :/

Comment: while stopped on the console.log line, execute in the browser `state.entries.push(newEntry)` and then try to check the `state.entries` array to see what's there, and add the same `debugger` in vuejs so you can inspect before and after the update... try to go through the entire flow until you find the culprit

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by sending the `entriesMonths` as a property to `MonthSelector.vue` component,

By that you're violating the purpose of having a store/getters/mutations, you can access the `entriesMonths` directly from your component, you don't have to pass it as a prop,

So change your `MonthSelector.vue` as follows:

- Remove the property that is passed to the component
- In your `slideOpts.initialSlide` access the `entriesMonths` directly from the store.

`initialSlide: this.$store.getters.entriesMonths.length - 1`

*Update: *

Please remove the `entriesMonths` from the `computed` properties and put it in `data` as follows:

```
  data() {
    const entriesMonths = this.$store.getters.entriesMonths
    return {
      entriesMonths,
      slideOpts: {
        initialSlide: entriesMonths.length - 1, // Start with newest slide/month
        speed: 300,
        pagination: false,
      },
    };
  },
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I did as you said, but with the same outcome: It runs with no errors at first, but throws the same errors when adding an entry. I found out that the new entry is successfully added to the store (by using debugger and viewing it in scope) and that also the `entriesMonths` gets re-caculated correctly.
Do you have any more ideas? (pushed changes to github)

Comment: @Julian Check the answer again I updated it (tried it and it works after cloning ur repo)

Comment: This indeed gets rid of the error message and allows me to add the entry to the store. However, the new entry will not be shown if from a new month - as `entriesMonths` is not updated. If using a computed property causes the error, maybe a watcher could be used..?